# Visual Studio portable library profile for both .Net Core 1.0 and Silverlight 5

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, silverlight-5.0, portable-class-library, asp.net-core-1.0

I'm using some portable libraries that use different targeting profiles (Profile344 and Profile259).  The key difference is that 344 references Silverlight 5 and not .Net Core 1.0, and 256 references .Net Core 1.0 and not Silverlight 5.  It appears there is no profile that supports both at the same time.  There is no common profile in which all libraries will build successfully.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Is there a way for me to create a new profile?

I actually need Silverlight 5 because it is the only decent solution for recording audio from a web page, at least on in a Windows browser.  For the new library I'm using for phone development with Xamarin (PortableRazor), it needs .Net Core 1.0 for some HttpUtility and type conversion stuff (at least).  I'm sharing common model and controller libraries for both a web app and phone apps.

Thanks.

-John

Comment: May be you are looking for something like this http://danrigby.com/2014/04/10/windowsphone81-pcl-xamarin-fix/

Comment: I saw that, but it didn't seem to help. By copying profile files I can get it to accept both .Net Core 1.0 and Silverlight 5 in the project properties UI, but it will still select an existing profile.  It seems there needs to be a new profile.  Has anyone got this to work?